# Fit video to window

Tags: html, video, size

I have been trying all the solutions on this site but none of them work. I would like a video to conform exactly to the size of the window. Why is this not working? I don't mind if the video has to letterbox in order to conform.

```
<video max width="100%" max height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" loop>
<source src="pianola trees.mp4" type="video/mp4"; object-fit="contain"/></video>
```

Additionally, there is a small border around the video, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Post the relevant code please? We can't help you very much without it.

Comment: Apologies. I've edited the question to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **video.js** to assist in your project.
https://github.com/videojs/video.js

---

If you are going to support dinosaur browser like IE 6, use flash version for overall support but never recommend it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Ideally, I would like to do this entirely in html. Is that possible?

Comment: Video support is far less for html only codings, yet if you intend to go for futuristic purpose i would recommend you to have a look at encoding.com. And this might help you too, http://v4e.thewikies.com/

Comment: Thank you. The code is so simple as it is. I was hoping that it would remain as simple to get the sizing right!

Comment: sizing is controlled with percentage on width attribute, i used it on my sites but had to be sure to support dinosaur browsers, so video js always served well.